# problem in hiding the keyboard when an editbox is clicked in Android app

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, android-edittext

in my app i am having an edit text box. When the user clicks the edit box i want to show him a alert box at that time i dont want the keyboard to be popped up. For this my code is as follows

```
bd =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);
bd.setHint("Birth Date");
bd.setOnClickListener(bdListener); 



private OnClickListener bdListener = new View.OnClickListener()
 {
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
      hidesoftkeyboard();
      DOBalert();
     }
 }




private void hidesoftkeyboard()
  {
    InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(bd.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
```

But still the keyboard is not hiding, where i am going wrong please help me friends

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: @Ravi Vyas - i think that question some what different sir

Comment: I needed the same thing last week and the solution @Vinayak gave worked for me , the same is documented in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard as the second top rated answer.

Comment: But this is not working for me why so.....

Comment: Could it be possible to share some more code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the above said answers is not working for me and at last i changed the edit boxes to be a text view.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your hidesoftkeyboard() method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Or

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: this is not working for me and fr my urgency i changed the edit text to text view

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode=[         "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible",
                                       "adjustResize", ] >
```

Use some of this in your manifest, this will hide the automatic keyboard pop up. However, if you are using your EditText for some input at time you'll need the keyboard. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this in ur activity

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
       hidesoftkeyboard();          
       return ret;
    }
```